# How to take max value from the integer

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

```
Dim a, b, c, d as int32

a = 20
b = 30
c = 15
d = 25
```

From the above 4 value, i need to take max value.

so the max value is `b = 30`

How to get max value.

Comment: You most likely want to use arrays for this. Go and read a proper book about vb.net.

Comment: It seems that everyone is a programming master. Please be polite with novice people, I believe this question doesn't need downvotes and it shouldn't be closed. Check my answer, OP found it useful. Thank you.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, this user has nearly 1300 rep and has *asked over 300 questions over two years*.  The user has also answered *zero* questions.  I'm going to argue that he's a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) and should be discouraged from asking such simplistic questions.  I'm not sure that this question deserves to be at -6, but still.

Comment: @Charles I see, but maybe best solution is avoid answering any question from him instead of closing it. Anyway, as I've few time for answering question, I'm not checking OP's activity... Thanks for the explanation, I'll take that in account when I see massive downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq extension methods (System.Linq namespace) if you add these values to some collection:

```
Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer) { 20, 30, 15, 25 };

Dim maxNumber As Integer = numbers.Max();
```